# Git lfs temp object is exceeding the size limit

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I having this weird error when I'm trying to push my commits. All the big files are tracked in lfs and the gitattributes is uploade on the origin but it seems to failing to upload some random lfs object. I haven't found any answers online, only for files from the repo which is not my case.

Any idea how to solve this? This is the error I'm getting

> Uploading LFS objects: 100% (22/22), 107 MB | 0 B/s, done.
> POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
> remote: error: Trace: de260b5ebbc2ff8bb2db7412c82aa3cf5c4f90d8ea2dd3e59a45e8d724b23e07
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
> remote: error: File lfs/objects/9a/57/9a57b5cfe6049e37fbee31800dfea03a34cbd80e237f0a3e57fe804c2099276c is 120.45 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

And this is from lfs logs

> $ git-lfs.exe filter-process
> Unable to move X:\Repo.git\lfs\tmp\2631776496 to X:\Repo.git\lfs\objects\32\27\3227898f95b5f5b6926c44a09eef71ccf3a743e594a6c8edd4533b3315537d0c
> rename X:\Repo.git\lfs\tmp\2631776496 X:\Repo.git\lfs\objects\32\27\3227898f95b5f5b6926c44a09eef71ccf3a743e594a6c8edd4533b3315537d0c: Access is denied.

Thank in advance, and sorry if this was already answered.

Comment: Have a look at ` git lfs ls-files`

Comment: You have some existing commit(s) that are storing large files directly, not via LFS. You must replace these commits with new and "improved" ones in which the large files aren't in the commits and are in LFS instead. See any answer involving `git lfs migrate`.